# create unique tracking code on creation of model on large tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `Question` model with these fields :

```
question_id //auto_increment 
code //=> unique tracking code
text
answer
confirmed
parent //=> a question can has a parent question that id of that placed here
created_at
updated_at
```

`code` field holds a unique integer value that used to tracking a question.

To create a unique integer I wrote these codes on model creation event:

```
class Question extends Model

    {
    public static function boot()
        {
        parent::boot();
        static ::creating(
        function ($model)
            {
            if (empty($model->attributes['parent']))
                {
                do
                    {
                    $code = rand(10000, 10000000);
                    $user_code = Question::where('code', $code)->get();
                    }

                while (!$user_code->isEmpty());
                }
              else
                {
                $parentQuestion = Question::findOrFail($model->attributes['parent']);
                $code = $parentQuestion->code;
                }

            $model->code = $code;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I used a `do-while` loop to create and check that generated number is used before on the table or not.

The reason is that I've not used a auto_increment beacause questions can have a parent that in this case , these questions and their parent should have same tracking code.

But Now my `questions` table have about **30,000** records that I think it could imposes high efficiency table and be slow on this large table.

Is my approach is correct and best way to do that?Or why is best way ?

**Update:**

I do not want to use sequential tracking code. because users may could access to tracking code of other users.

Comment: So the questions is about creating a unique id, efficiency of table look-up as it gets larger or...?

Comment: @Andrew , I want to know that approach is best way to create unique ids on large table or no?

Comment: So you're basically look for some sort of actual random token?

Comment: Yes, of course best approach of that for large tables

Comment: Does it have to be strictly numerical?

Comment: I prefer the the numeric user for simplicity but if I have a combination of numbers and letters can be.

Comment: Well you can use [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) to generate a random token. You can read from `/dev/random`, you could also use [`random_int`](http://php.net/random_int) if you're using PHP 7.x. [Random lib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib) is nice too. [`unique_id`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.uniqid.php) is also an option. Personally for the closest thing to actual random I'd use `/dev/random`, very very small chance of collision.

Comment: And what about code existence in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Much better way to create unique number is to get last code and add 1:

```
$newUniqueCode = Question::orderBy('code', 'desc')->first()->code + 1;
```

Or to use DB auto increment feature.

Comment: I updated question. I do not want to use sequential tracking code. because users may could access to code tracking of other users.